# Why does it take 10x the time to execute this task in a thread than not?

Tags: c#

I've ran into a problem and I don't know why it is happening. I'm loading items into my listview and because there are 20.000+ items which needs to be added, I'd like to  do it in a thread, but however it's taking super long to execute compared to non thread.

```
private void mainFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    airportListView.Items.Clear();

    var loadingThread = new Thread(loadData);
    loadingThread.Start();
}


private void loadData()
{
    foreach (var currAirport in Program.AirportManager.Airports)
    {
        var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(currAirport.Name);
        listViewItem.SubItems.Add(currAirport.ID);
        listViewItem.SubItems.Add(currAirport.Country);

        airportListView.Items.Add(listViewItem);
    }
}
```

This is taking at least 10x the time than this is needing:

```
private void mainFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    airportListView.Items.Clear();

    foreach (var currAirport in Program.AirportManager.Airports)
    {
        var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(currAirport.Name);
        listViewItem.SubItems.Add(currAirport.ID);
        listViewItem.SubItems.Add(currAirport.Country);

        airportListView.Items.Add(listViewItem);
    }
}
```

Does anybody have a clue why this is happening? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Making multiple threads to insert data into the primary UI thread is not going to be faster. If all goes well, the UI thread will lock each of the contributing threads, forcing them to insert their data one at a time. If that locking doesn't happen, you'll have race conditions. You might need to look into a different way of getting a lot of data on the screen at once, like using ObjectListView.

Comment: I'm not wanting it to be faster, I just want the UI to be responsive while adding the data, that's the reason I've added that Thread. It's currently just one Thread which inserts data into the ListView but as far as I can think it shouldn't take longer than inserting it without a thread?

Comment: @lokko Why are you putting 20,000 items in a list view, only load a page of data?

Comment: As Kevin said, my best guess is that every time you add an item you need to 1) pause your current thread, 2) switch to the GUI thread, 3) add your data, 4) release the GUI thread and go back to yours

Comment: I added code that will perform all at once, once the collection is done, so the GUI should remain responsive.

Comment: Do it in the main thread, and wrap it in `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate.aspx

Comment: Or create all the items first and use `AddRange`, as suggested on that page.

Comment: @lokko do not load 20,000 items in to the control - is the user really that interested in them all? Have a search mechanism and only populate with items matching the search criteria, or as johnny_5 recommends apply a pagination effect - 50 records per page for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the case because GUI items try to be thread safe.  Essentially, when you add an item to the ListView in another thread, it very well might be invoking a method on the GUI thread each time you add an item, or at the very least, invoking a locking mechanism of some sort, degenerating performance in the act.

You should perform operations on GUI items on the GUI thread.

If you want the GUI to be responsive while you are adding, collect all the items, then use AddRange() after they are all collected.

```
List<ListViewItem> toAdd = new List<ListViewItem>();    

private void mainFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    airportListView.Items.Clear();

    var loadingThread = new Thread(loadData);
    loadingThread.Start();
 }


private void loadData()
{
   foreach (var currAirport in Program.AirportManager.Airports)
   {
        var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(currAirport.Name);
        listViewItem.SubItems.Add(currAirport.ID);
        listViewItem.SubItems.Add(currAirport.Country);

        toAdd.Add(listViewItem);
    }
    airportListView.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        airportListView.Items.AddRange(toAdd);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed, but u should change airportListView.Items.AddRange(toAdd); to airportListView.Items.AddRange(toAdd.ToArray());